How can I force Playwright to ignore the SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL environment variable?
I have established the connection to the remote selenium greed, using SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL system environment. In this case Playwright sees this env and starts test remotelly by himself, I mean I don't make any additional in the code and don't set URL in the code:
    public BrowserType.LaunchOptions launchOptions() {
        return new BrowserType.LaunchOptions()
                .setHeadless(false)
                .setArgs(browserArgs())
                .setChannel("chrome");
    }

But now I can't start playwright locally! For this possibility I have to delete my system environment, but I don't want to do it all the time.
I have tried to set the path to the chrome.exe directly, but it isn't solving the issue:
    public BrowserType.LaunchOptions launchOptions() {
        return new BrowserType.LaunchOptions()
                .setHeadless(false)
                .setArgs(browserArgs())
                .setChannel("chrome")
                .setExecutablePath(Path.of(path-to-chrome));

    }

How can I force Playwright to ignore the SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL environment variable?
Or, in other words, force Playwright to start browser locally

There is no way to make playwright ignore that env variable. You will need to wipe the env variable. You can also create a feature request sharing your scenario https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues
